# Simon Funk vs. Matlabs SVDS

Tags: matlab, recommendation-engine, svd

I want to build an recommender system using Simon Funks' algorithm.
The idea is to first construct the model offline in Matlab to perform some evaluation on the results to what number of features (or dimensions) gives the best performance.

I have a matrix with users x items, where the rating '0' means that the user has not given a rating for that item.

So far I have tried to implement Simon Funks' algorithm in Matlab (see source-code) below, but it performs really (!) bad. By accident I found Matlab's SVDS function to fill the empty ratings and it actually performs better and faster then my Simon Funks' function

Could someone tell me what could be cause of this? Or tell me what stupid mistake I have made in Matlab function? :P

```
function ratings = simon_funk(original_ratings, dimensions) % To construct a complete rating matrix

% See: http://www.timelydevelopment.com/demos/NetflixPrize.aspx

% Variables
global max_features;    max_features = dimensions;
global init;            init = 0.1;

min_epochs = 2;
max_epochs = 16;
min_improvement = 0.001;
lrate = 0.01;
k = 0.015;

respondent_count = size(original_ratings, 1);
item_count = size(original_ratings, 2);
rating_count = 0;

data = [];
for r=1:respondent_count
    for i=1:item_count
        rating = original_ratings(r,i);
        if(rating > 0)
            data = [data; [r, i, rating, 0]];
            rating_count = rating_count + 1;
        end    
     end
end
% Now data contain all ratings in the form [user_id, item_id, rating, cache (default 0)]

ratings = zeros(respondent_count, item_count);
global item_features;       item_features = zeros(max_features, item_count);
global respondent_features; respondent_features = zeros(max_features, respondent_count);

% Init
item_features(:,:) = init;
respondent_features(:,:) = init;

% CalcFeatures
rmse_last = 2.0;
rmse = 2.0;

for f=1:max_features
    for e=1:max_epochs
        sq = 0;
        rmse_last = rmse;


        for r=1:rating_count
           % for i=1:item_count

           respondent = data(r,1);
           item = data(r,2);
           rating = data(r,3);

            % Predict rating
            p = simon_funk_predict_rating(data(r,:), f, 1);
            err = (1.0 * rating - p);
            sq = sq + err*err;

            rf = respondent_features(f,respondent);
            mf = item_features(f, item);

            % Cross-train the features
            respondent_features(f, respondent) = respondent_features(f,respondent) + (lrate * (err * mf - k * rf));
            item_features(f, item) = item_features(f, item) + (lrate * (err * rf - k * mf));
           % end
        end

        rmse = sqrt(sq/rating_count);

        %if (e >= min_epochs && rmse > (rmse_last - min_improvement))
        if ((e >= min_epochs) && ((rmse_last - rmse) < min_improvement))
            break;
        end
    end
    % Caching
    for r=1:rating_count
        data(r, 4) = simon_funk_predict_rating(data(r,:), f, 0);
    end 
end

% return new ratings set
for r=1:respondent_count
    for i=1:item_count
        sum = 1;

        for f=1:max_features
            sum = sum + item_features(f,i) * respondent_features(f,r);
            if(sum > 10)
            %    sum = 10;
            end

            if(sum < 1)
             %   sum = 1;
            end

        end
        ratings(r,i) = sum;
    end
end
```

And the function to predict an individual rating:

```
function sum = simon_funk_predict_rating(rating, f, bTrailing)
global item_features;
global respondent_features;
global max_features;
global init;
respondent = rating(1,1);
item = rating(1,2);
cache_value = rating(1,4);

sum = 1;
if(cache_value > 0)
    sum = cache_value;
end

sum = sum + (item_features(f,item) * respondent_features(f,respondent));

if (sum > 10) 
    %sum = 10;
end

if (sum < 1) 
    %sum = 1;
end


if (bTrailing == 1)
    sum = sum + (max_features - f - 1) * (init * init);
    if (sum > 10) 
        sum = 10;
    end
    if (sum < 1) 
        sum = 1;
    end
end
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you asking why a profesionally implemented command outperforms your own code snippet? If you want to figure out where time is wasted, use the profiler. If you want to figure out why results are not great, evaluate sample cases. This is just nog enough information to see if and your code performs `really bad`.